# How to print a string with values in it?

Tags: c++

I am trying to print out the address value that I stored in the string. After I compile, it shows error: `no match for 'operator<<'`. Does that mean what inside the `Address_list` is not matched something?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include "IPHost.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    map<string, IPHost> Address_list;
    Address_list["google.com"]=IPHost(74,125,225,20);
    cout << "google.com has address" << Address_list["google.com"] << endl; 
}
```

Comment: does IPHost have operator<< overloaded?

Comment: Or does it have some kind of "to string" functionality?

Comment: The `<<` operator does not know how to output an `IPHost` object by default. You have to implement an overload by yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Address_list["google.com"]
```

would return instance of `IPHost class` which you stored earlier. And then it would try to apply `operator<<` to that instance for which it's emitting error.

This means you have not overloaded operator<< for your `IPHost class`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others you need an overloaded operator<< for IPHost...

...which you would do like this:

```
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const IPHost& host)
{
   // code to stream the contents of IPHost out to os here
   // for example:
   os << "IPHost{" << host.address() << "}";

   // remember to return a reference to the ostream
   return os;
}
```